# Похожие товары по произвольному полю!

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

В Вукоммерсе есть плагины Related products, но они отбирают товары по категориям и меткам, но нет плагина который отбирал бы по произвольному полю, такая функция вообще есть в woocommerce?

Comment: Такой функции нет. Можно посмотреть код Related products и сделать свою выборку по базе. Ничего особенно сложного.

Answer (score 0):

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать Related products по произвольному полю, а то у меня уже знания закончились!?

В этом коде перепробовал кучу вариков может это не здесь?

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
exit;
```

}
if ( $related_products ) : ?>

```
<section class="related products">

    <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Related products', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

        <?php foreach ( $related_products as $related_product ) : ?>

            <?php
                $post_object = get_post( $related_product->get_id() );
                setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object );
                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

</section>
```